# Printing HTML generated text issue : some letters incompletely printed

Tags: html, css, printing, fonts

I am generating a document in HTML and have some text in a div.

```
<div style="font-size:8pt; font-weight:normal>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr><td>
     My text @@ pgt
  </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Before I used Lucida Console font and everything was fine.

I had to switch to Times New Roman and the following issue occurs :

It displays properly on the screen, but when I try to print that, the bottom of some letters like 'p, g, @' is cutted and does not display.

The issue is only on the printing. The printer is the same and settings have not been touched.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what if you reduced the `line-height` and `word-spacing`, when using `Times New Roman Font family`.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Thanks for your answer. I have not set up any line height. What would be a proper value for a Times new roman 8pt ?

Comment: I am not sure how to help you..but have a look at this link might helpful for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: I have tried 100%, 8pt also, but it is the same issue.

Comment: But now with 110% it worked :) Thanks :)

Comment: Glad your problem solved.